# Delete post from facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

my app on facebook post to wall of user who read any article on my website. I need to give user option to delete the post after they publish by clicking on the button just like yahoo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from the facebook documentation

> Delete
>
> You can delete a post as long as your application created the post.
>   You delete a post by issuing an HTTP DELETE request to the POST_ID
>   object with publish_stream permission.
>
> If the delete is successful, you get the following return `succeeded` boolean

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help,

```
var postId = '1234567890';
FB.api(postId, 'delete', function(response) {
if (!response || response.error) {
alert('Error occured');
} else {
alert('Post was deleted');
}
});
```

Refer this : (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/)